# Enable viewstate in php and Html

Tags: html, forms, viewstate

I am trying to make an html form submit data for processing to a php form. This works fine but when the data is validated and there are errors, somehow the data is cleared from the fields. I will like to know if there is a way to maintain the contents of the form controls even if I call the form on the php page that does the validation. I am a student and am new to php so please forgive me if I sound childish. Any elaborate explanation is welcomed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the validations are static use javascript to do so.
but if you are doing things with PHP (getting data from DB and such) I recommend that you pass all the field info thru a get or post to be "RE-FILLED"

Comment: Can you kindly show me an example of doing that. Or would you prefer I post the code here instead?

Comment: what are you validating ? a registration form ?

Comment: well u can go define "Zero/null values variables corresponding to the  number of fields you have then check if the POST or get hold values and assign the value if they exist , then go to each field and place in its value ... value="<?php echo $variable ?>"